# Can Adobe DTM read JSON

Tags: adobe-analytics

Can Adobe DTM read JSON such as:

```
<script type="application/json">
{ 
    "analytics" : [{ 
            "dataLayer" : [{ 
            "tags" : [{ 
                "adobeAnalytics" : true 
        }], 
        "pageInfo" : [{ 
            "country" : "us", 
            "language" : "en", 
            "siteDescriptor" : "xxx", 
            "platform" : "web", 
            "domain" : "xxxxx" 
        }], 
        "activities" : [{ 
                "eventType" : "xxxxx", 
                "eventCity" : "xxxxx", 
                "eventDate" : "xxxxx" 
        }] 
      ]} 
    }] 
    }`
    </script>
```

Previously I had this as a JavaScript object and created data elements in DTM to read the JS Object. However, due to constraints on the project, we can no longer do this as JavaScript. Is it possible to keep the same structure, add the 'type="application/json"' and keep everything else the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at least not out of the box. You'd need to parse the JSON into a variable before being able to use it in DTM.

```
<script type="application/json" id="json-datalayer">
{
    "analytics": [{
        "dataLayer": [{
            "tags": [{
                "adobeAnalytics": true
            }],
            "pageInfo": [{
                "country": "us",
                "language": "en",
                "siteDescriptor": "xxx",
                "platform": "web",
                "domain": "xxxxx"
            }],
            "activities": [{
                "eventType": "xxxxx",
                "eventCity": "xxxxx",
                "eventDate": "xxxxx"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
</script>
```

Then within DTM you could do something similar to (very basic example)

```
JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-datalayer').innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this summer you can add the "AEM Context Hub Tool" and provide the custom JSON schema.  This will enable DTM to read & monitor JSON.